# Move cursor to next contentEditable - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor, contenteditable

what I am looking to do specifically is when i press enter it creates a new paragraph the cursor then moves to or selects the new content editable paragraph to begin typing but i cant seem to find a way to do it.

```
/*HTML Layout*/
<div id="wrap" contenteditable="true">
|| <----cursor posiiton
//*New paragraph content editable when enter is pressed
<p contenteditable="true">New Paragrpah</p>
</div>

/* JQuery Code */
if(event.which == 13){
event.preventDefault();
elem.append('<p>insert a new paragraph</p>');
$('#container *').attr('contenteditable','true');
$('p', elem).focus();}
```

anyone have any insight? would be much appreciated.

I know it is Possible to do it with and input field and .focus() But that wont work on a contentEditable there has to be a way of doing it.

Best Regards Patrick

Comment: Please include full code next time, i.e. event handlers as well or just give a copy directly to jsfiddle or something, so we can directly try and work on it. Why do you want to have a `contenteditable` item within a `contenteditable` item though?

Comment: I will put it onto Jsfiddle. I did that in-case the clicked on a content editable on a blank space but i suppose adding a click event to a blank space to add a new content editable would work just the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the parent `contenteditable`, set focus on new `contenteditable`, enable parent `contenteditable` and focus back on parent `contenteditable` (won't allow you to move outside of the current one otherwise in some browsers.).

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){

if(event.which == 13){

    event.preventDefault();

    var p = $('<p />').text("insert a new paragraph").attr('contenteditable','true').appendTo($('#wrap'));
   $('#wrap').attr('contenteditable','false');
   $(p).focus();
   $('#wrap').attr('contenteditable','true').focus();  

}

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/6AsHq/

Comment: Nikklas version works! I also worked it out for myself: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhendron/2WGen/1/

Comment: Glad you found a solution as well. The `contenteditable`'s certainly weren't working quite as I had expected.